# Bootstrap Horizontal form with input-append on textboxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form horizontal form in bootstrap but when I try to add input-append over the control fields, that field gets shifted towards the right.
I am not able to find the exact source of why it is happening... or if I am doing something wrong. I am trying to add a simple PWD with the password input field...

```
<form class="bs-docs-example form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
              <div class="controls input-append">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    <span class="add-on">PWD</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <label class="checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

here is a jsfiddle for it.. http://jsfiddle.net/zEUH4/

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to have the email and password field horizontally aligned or do you mean the PWD is shifted to right and you want it to be on left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the input-append class and move it up onto the control-group div that should fix your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/zEUH4/1/

```
<div class="control-group input-append">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <span class="add-on">PWD</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will cause content after the control-group to float left. See answer below by EpokK for correct format.

Answer (score 4):

The correct structure is :

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-append">
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
      <span class="add-on">PWD</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I second this answer as the correct structure. the accepted answer can screw up other elements in your control group. an additional issue I had was with sizing the `input` after this. you must first add a `span*` to the `<div class="input-append">` and then give your input a `class="span12"`. Simply applying your desired span to ONLY the `input` gives unintended results.

Answer (score 2):

The `.input-append` class adds `display: inline-block;` to the `<div>`. The `.controls` adds a `margin: 180px` to the `<div>` which is normally 180px from the left edge, but is now 180px from the `<label>`.

These 2 classes ware not intended to be used on 1 element.

```
<form class="bs-docs-example form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                <span class="add-on">PWD</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEUH4/2/)

Alternatively you set the `<div>` to `display: block`.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls input-append" style="display: block">
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="add-on">PWD</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh..ok.. I think I understand the problem now .. somehow I missed the display:inline-block there... but I think Billy's answer is more suitable (though I don't know which one is more accurate!)